# Ola Hallengren backup systax when excluding a database

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

I would like to backup most of the databases except the database DBA.
I use below syntax in the job step:

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
    @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', '-DBA'
    @Directory = N'G:\BACKUP',
    @BackupType = 'DIFF',
    @Verify = 'Y',
    @CleanupTime = 336,
    @CheckSum = 'Y',
    @LogToTable = 'Y'
```

But it gives an error:

> Msg 102, Sev 15, State 1, Line 3 : Incorrect syntax near '@Directory'. [SQLSTATE 42000]

I also tried:

```
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', -'DBA'
```

does not work either.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a single database be excluded from an AG backup?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205575/can-a-single-database-be-excluded-from-an-ag-backup)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it has to be

`@Databases =  'USER_DATABASES, -Db1'`

See https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html

Assuming you want to backup all User Databases except one named `DBA`, your statement should be:

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
    @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES, -DBA',
    @Directory = N'G:\BACKUP',
    @BackupType = 'DIFF',
    @Verify = 'Y',
    @CleanupTime = 336,
    @CheckSum = 'Y',
    @LogToTable = 'Y'
```

Comment: @kin USER_DATABASES is a command in Ola Halengren's scripts that backs up all user databases, not a database called USER_DATABASES. I'm not sure how you'd use it to backup just the database called USER_DATABASES

Comment: @Greg that means  USER_Databases - substitute it with names of user dbs that you want to backup. Hope that is clear.

Comment: @kin - https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html says that if you specify 'USER_DATABASES' then it will backup all user databases, the -databasename will exclude that from the list of all user databases

Comment: If you actually would have a database called USER_DATABASES, and you only want to perform a backup of that database, then you could do like this: @Databases = '[USER_DATABASES]'